# How to reload tableView data inside a perform(mutation: GraphQLMutation) function?

Tags: ios, swift, graphql, apollo

I have an app that uses GraphQL and apollo framework to show a tableView with a list of countries. I have a toolbar button that when clicked shows an alert dialogue allowing the user to enter the name of a country so it can be added to a database on AWS. The problem is that inside the perform(mutation: GraphQLMutation) function I am unable to fetch my data and reload my tableView to immediately display my changes. I am able to fetch my list with a separate bar button though.

I've tried looking through the documentation and stepping through the program but it seems like the fetch function and reload function are called too early inside the perform(mutation: GraphQLMutation) function because when the tableView is reloaded the country count is lower than the actual number of countries in the database. For instance, when adding a country, countriesCount will be 30 instead of 31. So when the tableView reloads it reloads before the new country is added.

```
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Country", style: .default) { (action) in

        if let newCountry = textField.text {
            let addCountryMutation = AddCountryMutation(name: newCountry)
            self.apollo.perform(mutation: addCountryMutation) { (result, error) in
                self.fetchQueryResults()
                print("Country Added")
            }
        }

}

extension FetchCountryTableVC {

    func fetchQueryResults() {
        apollo.fetch(query: countriesQuery) { (result, error) in

            if let countries = result?.data?.countries.count {
                self.countriesCount = countries
            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

}
```

I expect that after the mutation is performed the fetchQueryResults() function will run, fetching the country count and reloading the tableView so the list of countries will show the newly added country.

What actually happens is the tableView reloads without showing the updated data.

Comment: When It goes into completion of Apollo.fetch, Doesn't It refresh the model?

Comment: It looks like it does refresh the model but for some reason it does not refresh it with the current data. I can't u derstand why but when the code runs through the fetch it seems that it hasn't yet added the country. If I press a button and si.ply do a fetch by itself after entering a country it leads the model correctly.

Comment: Can you please put self.tableview.reloaddata inside if let and put debug there to check If It goes into that line?

Comment: Yes. When I placed the line inside the if let it does the same thing. That's actually where I originally had it because it made sense for it to be there but it still does not work.

Comment: Can you please share tableview delegate functions

Comment: I'm not sure which delegate functions you would like to see. I do not use a tableView delegate because I just say self.tableView to call the reloadData() function. I did previously try to make an IBOutlet for my tableView called CountriesTableView and use it to call self.CountriesTableView.reloadData() but that also did not work.